# Generic types on function don't correspond properly

Tags: list, types, functional-programming, f#

I have experience with functional programming in general, but I'm new to F#, and I can't get this code to compile no matter what I try:

```ml
let group2<'T> (sq: seq<'T>) : seq<'T * 'T> = 
    Seq.fold (fun (p, l) b -> match p with
                              | None   -> (Some b, l)
                              | Some v -> (None, (v, b) :: l)) (None, []) sq
```

I don't understand what this error message is trying to tell me, and I can't for the life of me figure out why it won't compile as-is;

```
main.fs(2,19): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'seq<'T * 'T>'    
but here has type
    ''a * 'b'    

main.fs(4,65): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'seq<'T * 'T>'    
but here has type
    ''a * 'b'
```

anyone with more F# experience have some advice?

Comment: I really don't know what you're trying to achieve.  Can you post some example values of what you think your function should return?  perhaps sample code in which ever other language you know well that achieves the same?

Comment: You can force compile if you add the lines     |> snd
    |> Seq.ofList aligned to Seq.fold but it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Your return type annotation is not what your code is doing. You're expecting a list of tuples, but you're creating a tuple of `(option, list)`

Comment: I should have been more clear, the function is supposed to pair every 2 elements into a list of tuples. I think what I didn't realize is that it actually returns the state, which contains an extraneous internal value, and the actual list to return as the two elements.

Comment: Please update the question with the information in your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you update your code like this

```
let group2<'T> (sq: seq<'T>) : seq<'T * 'T>  = 
    Seq.fold (fun (p ,l) b -> match p with
                              | None   -> (Some b, l)
                              | Some v -> (None, (v, b) :: l)) (None, []) sq
    |> snd
    |> List.rev
    |> Seq.ofList
```

It can work (by removing the state, and converting back from list to sequence). For example

```
group2 [1;2;3;4]
```

yields

```
[(1, 2); (3, 4)]
```

It's not very idiomatic as it mixes sequences and lists.

A more idiomatic code only for (even) lists:

```
let rec group2 (xs:'T list) =
    match xs with
    | [] -> []
    | x::y::xs -> ( x, y)::group2 xs
    | _ -> failwith "not even"
```

Basically you deal with 3 choices,

1. The list is empty, there are no pairs you return an empty list.
2. There are two items at the start, you pair them in a tuple and process the rest of the list recursively
3. There's only one item left, we fail because it's not posible to create a tuple with nothing*

If you want to consider odd lists, you can use option types: e.g. None/Some

```
let rec group2 (xs:'T list) =
    match xs with
    | [] -> []
    | [x] -> [Some x, None]
    | x::y::xs -> (Some x,Some y)::group2 xs
```

Finally you could use the chunkBySize library function for either (even) lists or sequences:

```
[1;2;3;4]
|> Seq.chunkBySize 2
|> Seq.map (fun a -> a.[0], a.[1])
```

or

```
[1;2;3;4]
|> List.chunkBySize 2
|> List.map (fun a -> a.[0], a.[1])
```